# Jquery height resize not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jquery to resize an image on a mobile website: http://www.loiristorantino.com.br/mobile

On browser, if you resize your screen, it works fine but on mobile it's not working. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
var $inner = $('.inner');
var height = parseInt($inner.height()) + parseInt($inner.css('top'));
$('.tumb-img-border').css('height', height);

var doit;

function resizedw(){
    var $inner = $('.inner');
    var height = parseInt($inner.height()) + parseInt($inner.css('top'));
    $('.tumb-img-border').css('height', height);
}
window.onresize = function() {
    clearTimeout(doit);
    doit = setTimeout(function() {
        resizedw();
        fontResuze();
    }, 100);
};
```

I think it's something related with Jquery but I don't know how to change it to javascript.

Can you guys help me with this issue?

Comment: Why don't you use only CSS? Please provide your HTML & CSS code.

Comment: You need to call resize on page load

Comment: I tried to achieve the same with pure css but no luck! Can you look at the source code? I guess it's too big to share it here.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, I tried to call it on window.onload but it's doesnt work

Comment: @fackz did you put same function in onload?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, yes:
window.onload = function() { resizedw(); }

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the solution by myself. Since I got this resize function on google, this solution might help others. I just changed the following line and it worked:

```
//var height = parseInt($inner.clientHeight());// + parseInt($inner.css('top'));
var newheight = $('.inner').height();
$('.tumb-img-border').css('height', newheight);
```